# Flutter - How can I let a user erase part of an image and make it transparent?

Tags: flutter, image, transparency, edit, erase

My goal is to let a user selected image (via image_picker) and then use an eraser type tool to modify that image and make it transparent.  Any ideas on how I should go about this?

Comment: Something like scratch the image?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is not really straight forward but you can try [image package](https://pub.dev/packages/image) out. So many things can be done with it.